# Specific Fields Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I try to select specific fields from my Qdata.txt file and use field[2] to calculate average for every years separate. My code give only total average.

data file looks like: (1. day of year: 101 and last: 1231)

> Date   3700300   6701500
>
> 20000101 21.00   223.00
>
> 20000102 20.00   218.00
>
> . .
>
> 20001231 7.40   104.00
>
> 20010101 6.70   104.00
>
> . .
>
> 20130101 8.37   111.63
>
> . .
>   20131231 45.00  120.98

```
import sys

td=open("Qdata.txt","r") # open file Qdata

total=0
count=0
row1=True

for row in td :
    if (row1) :
            row1=False # row1 is for topic

    else:
            fields=row.split() 
            try:
                    total=total+float(fields[2])
                    count=count+1
            # Errors.
            except IndexError:
                    continue
            except ValueError:      
                    print("File is incorrect.")
                    sys.exit()

print("Average in 2000 was: ",total/count)
```

Comment: You could use `itertools.groupby` using the first four characters as the key for grouping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use itertools.groupby using the first four characters as the key for grouping.

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    next(f) # skip first line
    groups = itertools.groupby(f, key=lambda s: s[:4])
    for k, g in groups:
        print(k, [s.split() for s in g])
```

This gives you the entries grouped by year, for further processing.
Output for your example data:

```
2000 [['20000101', '21.00', '223.00'], ['20000102', '20.00', '218.00'], ['20001231', '7.40', '104.00']]
2001 [['20010101', '6.70', '104.00']]
2013 [['20130101', '8.37', '111.63'], ['20131231', '45.00', '120.98']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `dict` (or even a `defaultdict`) for `total` and `count` instead:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

td=open("Qdata.txt","r") # open file Qdata

total=defaultdict(float)
count=defaultdict(int)
row1=True

for row in td :
    if (row1) :
        row1=False # row1 is for topic

    else:
        fields=row.split() 
        try:
            year = int(fields[0][:4])
            total[year] += float(fields[2])
            count[year] += 1
        # Errors.
        except IndexError:
            continue
        except ValueError:      
            print("File is incorrect.")
            sys.exit()

print("Average in 2000 was: ",total[2000]/count[2000])
```

Answer (score 0):

Every year separate? You have to divide your input into groups, something like this might be what you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict

row1 = True
year_sums = defaultdict(list)

for row in td:
    if row1:
        row1 = False
        continue
    fields = row.split()
    year = fields[0][:4]
    year_sums[year].append(float(fields[2]))

for year in year_sums:
    avarage = sum(year_sums[year])/count(year_sums[year])
    print("Avarage in {} was: {}".format(year, avarage)
```

That is just some example code, I don't know if it works for sure, but should give you an idea what you can do. `year_sums` is a `defaultdict` containing lists of values grouped by years. You can then use it for other statistics if you want.